# How to access other columns from DataSource Table in dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, webforms

I have a table of countries having 10 columns. I have already assigned **CityName** as `DataTextField` to my `DropDownList` and **Id** as `DataValueField`. Now on `SelectedIndexChanged` I have to get values from other columns like **CityCode**. How I can access it?

```
ddlCity.DataSource = cboxTeam_DS.Tables["MyTable"];
ddlCity.DataTextField  = "CityName";
ddlCity.DataValueField= "Id";
ddlCity.DataBind();
```

On `SelectedIndexChanged` method, how do I access the **CityCode** column values ?

Comment: Are you want to get `CityCode` for selected city?

Comment: You can get `CityCode` from database by passing selected `Id` of dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here is my solution which I have developed to solve this problem and it is very effective for me.

The first thing I did, I have changed my database query

from

```
SELECT * FROM Cities ORDER BY CityName Asc;
```

to

```
SELECT *, convert(nvarchar(10),id) + ',' + CityCode as idCode FROM Cities ORDER BY CityName Asc;
```

It returns me a table containing an extra column named as `idCode` .

As `id` is int and `CityCode` is nvarchar, so I convert the id column and gets an extra column contains values of both columns.

And in my code, I have assigned the `idCode` column to my `ddlCity.DataValueField`.

```
ddlCity.DataSource = cboxTeam_DS.Tables["MyTable"];
ddlCity.DataTextField  = "CityName";
ddlCity.DataValueField = "idCode";
ddlCity.DataBind();
```

After that I use comma splice to to split the string into `id` and `code` into an array.

```
string[] strArray = this.ddlCity.SelectedValue.Split(',');
```

And then use it where I want to use it by accessing the Indexes.

```
int myId = strArray[0];
string myCode = strArray[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you two ways of doing this

1. You can store one more hidden drop down with your Id and CityCode populated in it. So whenever you select the original drop down select the appropriate value from this hidden dropdown list.
2. Second way is when you get the ID from the `ddlCity.SelectedValue` you need to retrieve the table again with the criteria and search in your table taking this value as reference to get the City Code.

I prefer you to go for the first one. you can also access the hidden dropdown in the first case using the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have not bind the `CityCode` column to drop down. The data for `dropdown` is kept in `ViewState` and that does not know other columns. In desktop we can get the object from ComboBox (dropdown) but in asp.net we can not. This is probably to keep the ViewState as small as possible.

You can choose one of these method to accomplish what you need.

- You can get the `id` and send a database call to retrieve the `CityCode` in `SelectedIndexChanged`.
- You can make the `Value` column by combination of two columns like id_CityCode and later extract what you need.

Comment: You can make the Value column by combination of two columns like id_CityCode and later extract what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get directly from your datasource

```
 int CityId = (int)ddlCity.SelectedValue;
    DataTable dt = cboxTeam_DS.Tables["MyTable"];
    string CityCode = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
              where (int)dr["Id"] == CityId 
              select (string)dr["CityCode"]).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that with the ID, retrieve again the fields you need on the database. This way you save time and effort. That was how I solved it.